# How to access dynamically created element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the HTML structure, i have list of items which are styled as inline-block, and i'm wrapping the list with `<marquee> </marquee>` tags using JQuery since i'm not able to add id directly from the drupal8 view.

What i'm trying to do is i have 2 buttons left and right, when i click on the respective buttons the marquee should change the direction its moving.

Since its dynamically created element, i'm not able to access the element with jquery, i'm getting the error 'not defined'.

When i click on the right and left buttons i'm getting the below error

> marquee.start is not a function

```js
var $j = jQuery;

$j(".item-list > ul").wrap("<marquee class='scrollermarquee'></marquee>");

$j('.view-header').on('click', function() {
  var marquee = $j('.scrollermarquee').addClass('mia');
  marquee.stop();
  marquee.direction = 'left';
  marquee.start();
})

$j('.view-footer').on('click', function() {
  var marquee = $j('.scrollermarquee').addClass('mia');
  marquee.stop();
  marquee.direction = 'right';
  marquee.start();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view view-ticker view-id-ticker view-display-id-block_1 js-view-dom-id-95599754f8c1606496d24cbc4e81ab801ba6c7756348defe6e876248e992d5e0">
  <div class="view-header">
    <p><span class="leftbutton">&lt;</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="view-content">
    <div class="item-list">
      <marquee class="scrollermarquee mia">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="views-field views-field-title"><span class="field-content"><a href="/node/805" hreflang="en">test-report-3</a></span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="views-field views-field-title"><span class="field-content"><a href="/node/801" hreflang="en">test-report-1</a></span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="views-field views-field-title"><span class="field-content"><a href="/node/470" hreflang="en">test-report-2</a></span></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </marquee>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-footer">
    <p><span class="rightbutton">&gt;</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: then use `$(document).on(...`

Comment: are you adding buttons dynamically or list? post relevant html also

Comment: _“i'm getting the error 'not defined'”_ - where? Please provide a proper [mre], instead of just showing snippets and referring to errors without proper context.

Comment: `marquee` still exists?

Comment: Updated the above OP

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar buttons are not added dynamically, but marquee has been dynamically.

Comment: @ChandanRaikar you're trying to call `stop()`, `start()` and set the `direction` property on the jQuery object, not the marquee element itself. Use `marquee[0].stop()` etc. Also note that `<marquee>` has been deprecated for a *long* time, so I doubt the code you've got will work cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
You are selecting marquee element with jquery class selector and adding class to it which does not return the marque element and hence getting not defined value.

first get element and then add class, see below

```
$j('.view-header').on('click', function() {
  var marquee = $j('.scrollermarquee');
  marquee.addClass('mia');
  marquee[0].stop();
  marquee[0].direction = 'left';
  marquee[0].start();
})

$j('.view-footer').on('click', function() {
  var marquee = $j('.scrollermarquee');
  marquee.addClass('mia');
  marquee[0].stop();
  marquee[0].direction = 'right';
  marquee[0].start();
})
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for pointing out. I have corrected it in the post